# PHP Strict warning: Declaration of Child::set() should be compatible with Parent::set()?

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance

I have this

```
class A {...}
class B extends A {...}

class Parent {
    public function setObj(A $obj)  { .... }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    public function setObj(B $obj) { .... }
}
```

Whit this message :

> Strict warning: Declaration of Child::setObj() should be compatible with Parent::setObj(A $obj) in require_once()

Why do I get this warning ?

PHP 5.5.12 (in Drupal 7.38)

Comment: Because `public function setObj(A $obj)` !== `public function setObj(B $obj)`

Comment: Change `class Child extends Parent {
    public function setObj(B $obj) { .... }
}` to `class Child extends Parent {
    public function setObj(A $obj) { .... }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like

```
class A {...}
class B extends A {...}

class Parent {
    public function setObj(A $obj)  { .... }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    public function setObj(A $obj) { .... }
}
```

because you overwrite the `Parent::setObj(A)` with a method that has the same name, but an other signature.

See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227766/changing-method-signature-for-implementing-classes-in-php

Comment: Specifically the class type hint is different. If you want one but expect different types, use a common ancestor of both.